# object_setClass to bigger class

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, runtime, objective-c-runtime

I am changing the class of some objects using `object_setClass(id object, Class cls)`. I am changing the class to a **subclass** of the original class. Then I set some properties that are only defined on the subclass, and things seem to work fine.

I was a bit surprised that this worked, because `object_setClass`, as far as I understand, doesn't reallocate the object, it only changes the `isa` pointer. If the subclass instances are considerably larger (meaning having many more ivars) than the original class instances, I don't see how the object can work as expected.

Does this work only because there is a lot of buffer memory between objects in memory (due to alignment etc)?

Is this robust, or could it crash under some circumstances?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could crash. As can be seen in the source code of the runtime [here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.1/runtime/objc-class.m), it really just swaps the `isa` pointer.

If you really want to swap the `isa` to an `isa` of a subclass with more ivars, you should use [`class_createInstance`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-BBCJDEAJ) with nonzero `extraBytes`.

Comment: thanks, that's what I was afraid of and it makes sense of course. I don't see how your solution would help, because I don't want to create a new object. (I can't, because the object is a readonly property of another class.)

Comment: If it's your code, you can arrange  the property to be created with the extra bytes so that you can safely change the class later. But I don't think it's a good idea to swap the class of a readonly property! Why are you doing that?

Comment: I thought it was a clever little hack to modify a view loaded from a nib. But I'll resort to more standard methods.

Comment: You should use `objc_setAssociatedObject()` and `objc_getAssociatedObject()`. (I don't think these methods existed when the question was asked though…)

Comment: `class_createInstance` doesn't seem to exist anymore. Is there a replacement?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a larger subclass, use `objc_setAssociatedObject` and `objc_getAssociatedObject` to attach dynamically additional objects to your existing fixed-size object.