# How to allocate an NSObject subclass instance FROM an instance of its superclass?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, inheritance, subclass, nsobject

Given a class structure such as...

```
@interface SuperClassView : NSView                              @end
@interface SubClassedView : SuperClassView @property int aProp; @end
```

How can one instantiate a `SubClassedView` from an *instance* of a `SuperClassView`?

Say a method returns an instance of the superclass `SuperView`....

```
SuperClassView *superInstance = [ViewFactory makeSuperClassView];
```

but I *want* to get an instance of the ***subclass*** `SubClassedView`? It is not possible to simply "cast" it...

```
SubClassedView *subClsInstance = (SubClassedView*)[ViewFactory makeSuperClassView];
```

and there is no built-in (or easily-imagined implementation of an) `NSObject` method like

```
self = [super initWithInstance:[superInstance copy]];`
```

Is the only way to either copy the superclass instance's desired properties to the newly instantiated subclass object, like...

```
SubClassedView *subClsInstance = SubClassedView.new;
for (NSString* someKey in @["frame",@"color",@"someOtherProperty])
   [subClsInstance setValue:[superInstance valueForKey:someKey] forKey:someKey];
```

Or add (*swizzle at runtime*) the subclass' "additional property methods" (in this case `setAProp:` and `aProp`) to the superclass instance (and also cast it upwards)...

```
SubClassedView *subClsInstance = (SubClassedView*)[ViewFactory makeSuperClassView];
[subClsInstance addSwizzleMethod:@selector(setAProp:) viaSomeMagic:....];
[subClsInstance addSwizzleMethod:@selector(aProp)     viaSomeMagic:....];
```

Hopefully this is an easy *runtime trick* that I simply don't know... not a sad sign that I am haplessly trying to trick `ObjC` into multiple-inheritance via some *embarrassing anti-pattern*. Either way, ideas?

**EDIT:** Pending @BryanChen posting his comment as an answer this is achieved easily via his suggested runtime function, or as a category on `NSObject` á la..

```
@implementation NSObject (SettingClass)
- (void)setClass:(Class)kls { if (kls) object_setClass(self, kls); } @end
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Change the class of an instance? There is `object_setClass`

Comment: Can you say in one sentence what you are trying to accomplish? Do you want to create a copy of a prototype?

Comment: @BryanChen yes, this is exactly what I want... post it as an answer... here's an example...  `SuperClassView *x = SuperClassView.new; object_setClass(x,[SubClassedView class]); SubClassedView *z = x; z.aProp = 2;`  Yay!

Comment: Simply create the subclass in the superclass and return it.  It does take a little dance with forwarded pointers, et al, but it can be done.  Keep in mind that when the subclass init method calls the super method then all items the super init method sets will be set in your subclass.

Comment: (And lots of classes have something like `initWithInstance` method.  It's only code.)

Comment: @HotLicks  i guess I was trying to avoid a convoluted factory method and/or having to manually/introspectively iterate over the superclass object's properties.

Comment: It's only code.  (I'm a little confused as to why so many people seem to be afraid of writing code, especially when, as in this case, it's reasonably straight-forward and well-defined.)

Answer (score 6):

What you are trying to do is pretty non-idiomatic... it feels like you are trying to do something like prototype based OOP. A couple of quick points:

1. Don't do the swizzle. You can't swizzle onto an instance, you swizzle onto the class definition, so if you do that you won't be adding the subclasses methods onto "an" instance of the superclass, you will be adding them onto all instances of the superclass.
2. Yes, if you want to do this you just need to copy the the properties you want from the super into the new instance of the subclass.
3. You can have a factory method in the superclass that returns a subclass, and encapsulate all the the copying in there (so, `-[SuperClassView makeSubclassView]` that returns `SubClassedView *`. That is actually relatively common, and is how many of the class clusters are implemented (though they return private subclasses that conform to the implementation of the superclass)

Comment: @BryanChen: You can swizzle methods on a single instance of a class? How would you go about that?

Comment: create a private subclass, swizzle the private subclass, set class of the instance to the private subclass. this is how [KVO implemented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOImplementation.html).

Comment: @Chuck [check out my per instance method swizzling implementation](https://github.com/mralexgray/AtoZ.framework/blob/a7393bb9e6efd9227d680515b773e827d8f10d31/AtoZ/Categories/NSObject-Utilities.h) which allows you to "Dynamically override the specified method on a particular instance."  It's a SUPER convenient alternative to subclassing or if you want to have several, slightly different implementations depending on runtime conditions..

Answer (score 1):

`object_setClass` is not the droid you're looking for.

Yes, it will change the *class* of the instance.  However, it will not change the *size* of it.  So if your `SubClassView` declares extra properties or instance variables that are not declared on `SuperClassView`, then your attempts to access them on this frankenstein instance will result in (at best) buffer overflows, (probably) corrupted data, and (at worst) your app crashing.

It sounds like you really just want to use `self` in your factory method:

```
+ (instancetype)makeView {
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

Then if you call `[SuperClassView makeView]`, you get back an instance of `SuperClassView`.  If you call `[SubClassView makeView]`, you get back an instance of `SubClassView`.

"But," you say, "how do I customize the properties of the view if it's a `SubClassView`?"

Just like you would with anything else: you override the method on `SubClassView`:

```
@implementation SubClassView

+ (instancetype)makeView {
    SubClassView *v = [super makeView];
    v.answer = 42;
    return v;
}

@end
```

Comment: Dave this is all true, but requires that the factory method be a function of the view's class structure...  I meant to imply some "less-informed", "external factory" - that may be clueless as to the subclass structure of the `SuperClassView`.

Comment: Also, I thought your observation about the size would be true myself, but in the example in response to @BryanChen I gave... I AM able set and get the "new" or shall I say "inherited" property on the re-classified super object just fine.  Is that just a lucky example or is the runtime compensating for the "size difference" somehow?

Comment: @alexgray it's totally lucky. `object_setClass` does an OSAtomicCompareAndSwap on the slot in memory.  It does little else.

Comment: I **think** you could solve the ivar/property problem by using ObjC's associated object storage APIs and bypassing auto-synthesis.  Not pretty, but it might be a viable work-around.

Answer (score 0):

[`object_setClass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_setClass) may or may not be the "runtime trick" you are looking for. It does isa swizzle which change the class of an instance at runtime. However it does have many constrains such as that the new class cannot have extra ivars. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346427/object-setclass-to-bigger-class) for more details.

I think the better way to do is that instead of making view using `[ViewFactory makeSuperClassView]`, make it `[[SuperClassView alloc] initWithSomething]`. Then you can do `[[SubClassView alloc] initWithSomething]`

or if you really want use `ViewFactory`, then make it `[ViewFactory makeViewOfClass:]`

Comment: The problem is that `NSObject` doesn't have an `initWithSomething:` method.

Comment: you should define it in `SuperClassView`

Comment: You should not use `object_setClass`.  See my answer for why.